# How to run .ARFF of weka in Mahout

Tags: weka, mahout

Is there any WEKA support availbale in Mahout ? I have a .ARFF file but I want to run it in Mahout for classification using SVM or Naive Bayesian. Can anyonw tell where to start ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Mahout does support ARFF files; there is a command [to convert ARFF files to vectors for Mahout](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Creating+Vectors+from+Weka%27s+ARFF+Format).

Something along the lines of the following command is probably what you are looking for:

```
$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout arff.vector -d /path/to/arff_file \
    -t /path/to/dictionary -o /path/to/output
```

The dictionary file contains a mapping of the label bindings for each vector in the output file.